# Fix blurry view of embedded Visio diagram in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-office, resolution, microsoft-visio, microsoft-onenote

From within OneNote, I inserted a new Visio File.
Everything looks good in Visio, but when I switch to OneNote the resolution of my Visio view in OneNote is blurry.

Note: It has an odd artifact when I zoom in, the resolution improves for a moment and then, settles at a worse resolution.

From Visio:

[image: Snip from Visio]

From OneNote:

[image: Snip from OneNote]

Note: The Visio diagram is a decent size if that matters.
[image: Scale of Visio diagram in OneNote]

Comment: Did you insert Visio using [this method](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/add-a-visio-diagram-to-a-page-in-onenote-d36c2408-5e8c-44b6-b152-1b22b83d3462)? See the section "Embed a static image of the diagram".

Comment: Older versions of One Note needed Hardware acceleration disabled.   Not newer versions.  Try a new Video driver for you system.

Comment: @harrymc Yes I did that process. The Visio diagram was created from the OneNote using [Insert > Files > Diagram > New Visio Drawing].

Comment: @John my OneNote version is 2312 and from what read on https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-disable-hw-acceleration-of-onenote/c49d866b-4ebb-473e-8fab-6517c88b8915 Microsoft has removed the ability to toggle Hardware acceleration like you mentioned. Also, this is a work computer and I don't have permission to experiment with video drivers.

Comment: Yes. Current Versions do not offer the Hardware Acceleration settings. I did note that. Ask your IT support for a new Video Driver.